# Lotus Foundations

Tags: ibm

Has anyone looked at [IBM Lotus foundations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_Foundations).

> Lotus Foundations is a bundled small-business server solutions package by IBM. The package includes Lotus Domino, directory services, file management, firewall, backup and various productivity tools. The product's release is a direct result of IBM's acquisition of Net Integration Technologies, which has been integrated into the IBM Lotus division. The original pre-acquisition product was based around the Net Integrator Mark 1 server appliance and its NITIX Autonomic Linux Server OS.

They claim that this appliance can replace a system administrator for small to medium companies. What do you guys think about this.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that would depend how you feel about [Lotus Notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Lotus_Domino). Personally I would rather be stabbed in the eyes repeatedly than ever use that software again, but opinions vary.

Comment: funny, I have similar feelings about MS software

Answer (score 1):

I have a drawer full of golden hammers from vendors promising me the moon and the stars.